# Codeblocks/GCC being stubborn about compiling C

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

Im really new to C and just got Codeblocks to compile/run any code that I write and I can't make it run this block of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("\nHello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could list out how to make it do something it would really be appreciated

(Maybe its just me but it seems like theres alot going on, I mean theres alot of shiny buttons)

Comment: could you please be more specific? do you have any errors to discuss?

Comment: write all your code in Kate and run it in bash :]

Comment: Are you sure that it is not running, terminating, and closing its window (faster than the human eye)!?  If you are getting error messages, post them - give us a clue!  There is nothing wrong with the code, it is the tool and its configuration, or what I just suggested.  In that sense you are on the wrong forum, try [forums.codeblocks.org](http://forums.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: "Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
Nothing to be done.  This is what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select File->New->Project from the menu

From the "New from template" window, select "Console application"

Run through the wizard and give your project a title. (Select defaults if you don't know what to set)

From the workspace manager (shift+F2), expand the dropdown through your project,the sources folder, and select main.cpp

Copy your code into the pre-built main.cpp file.

From the top menu, select Build, and then the "Build and Run" option.

And that should do it.

Comment: "Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
Nothing to do. !!!!

Comment: You do have gcc and g++ installed , right ?  You confirmed this from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, it works on my system (OSX Snow Leopard):

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("\nHello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
$ make foo
cc -Os -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -arch x86_64 -fno-common -fPIC -DHAVE_NETCDF  -arch x86_64  foo.c   -o foo
Thunderball:tmp james$ ./foo 

Hello, world!
$
```